# spresenseのLTE通信手順と消費電力、接続時間

Tags: spresense

Spresenseで、LTE通信の間隔を数秒〜1分程度で繰り返し行っており、できれば消費電流を抑えたいと考えています。
LTE通信をする場合、電源ON時に初期設定とSETUP(attachまで)を行ない、サーバーへの送信時にconnectをしています。この状態だとモデム電源ONになっており、通常時の消費電力が大きくなっているよう思うのですが、一般的に、電源ON時はどこまでの処理を行うものでしょうか。
サーバーへの送信時にSETUP(begin= LTE_SEARCHINGから)から実施していると、送信時に時間がかかってしまうと思いますので、送信時の接続時間が長くなり、消費電力も大きくなるようにも思います。
また、LTE通信でconnectしたままの場合、接続された状態のままになりますでしょうか。どこかでタイムアウト等で切断されるものでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

｢数秒～1分」というのがものすごく微妙な話なので、自分で要件にあわせて検証するしかない話に思えます。

PCとかスマートフォンでの話になりますが、オフライン状態から(おそらく)通信可能な状態となるまで｢数秒」はかかります。その遅れが許せないなら消費電力無視してつなぎっぱなしにするしかありません。

1分、というのがデータ収集周期の都合なのかタイムラグの限界値なのかは質問からは読み取れません。前者であればタイムラグを無視すれば(極端には1年に1回とか)消費電力は押さえられます。後者だとすると(要するに「数秒」は無視して1分ごと送信にする)、都度接続した方がいいような気はしますが、キャリアとか設置環境にも引っ張られます。

> また、LTE通信でconnectしたままの場合、接続された状態のままになりますでしょうか。

何らかの理由で待機中または通信中に切断されることは考えられるので、取りこぼしが許されないのであればリトライが必須になります。